# During a function call how can I use rest parameters in Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, postman, nestjs

I am working on nestjs and I want to retrieve data from DB on the basis of name property, which I am passing in a method of services code. The issue is when am passing {"name": "item1"} in postman, am getting item1 related data, but when am passing {"name":"item1","name":"item2"} in postman, I am getting data related to item2 only.I want to retrieve data of both item1, item2, and so on. To overcome this issue I thought rest parameters would be a good choice, but I don't know how to pass rest parameters and how to call rest parameters in postman. The main problem is I don't know how to deal with rest parameters in postman and code too.

Here is the code of services:

```
async individual(...name:any){
    const ind= await this.usersmodel.find({'name':{$in:name}})
    return ind
}
```

Here is the code of controller:

```
@Post('ind')
async ind(@Body('name')name){
    return this.usersService.individual(name)
}
```

screenshot of postman:
[image]

screenshot of error am getting by using this method:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your question isn't well formulated but i will pretend you are trying to find in your schema a number of values that you will provide trought your API.

Thinking that way, you can use a POST to sendo an Array inside your body, like that:

```
"name": ["item2", "item3", "item4"]
```

Inside your service file you receive that array and can still use find(), but that way:

```
await this.usersmodel.find({
'name': { $in: name }
}
```